# Reduction in radiator water level

Tags: toyota, highlander

I just bought a 2nd hand 2005 Toyota Highlander and after taken it on a short trip, I discovered the radiator water level had gone down significantly. What could be the problem?

Comment: How's the temperature while driving?  I'd wonder if the coolant was changed just before sale, and its burped an air-bubble.   Top it up with clean water and repeat the short trip, then check again.